# MySQL table filed with text datatype inserting some script value automatically and ignored user input

Tags: mysql, datatypes

In my MY-SQL database table having with text datatype.  In that field having some unwanted script tag added automatically.  If I given that any value also ignored.

and also I tried to edit that value  with update command but I couldn't.

and tried to re-create that table, but getting same value. Here I verified and there no any triggers.

Herewith attached the screen shot for reference:
[image]

Comment: Add the table definition and mention the insert and update statement, it will help to debug the issue.

Comment: This is a client error, not a MySQL error.  Period; Full Stop.